# AWS Cloudwatch alarms is not going back to OK state from alarm state, Notifying SNS topic for three consecutive period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I've created ALARM for lambda([ERRORS]) on custom metric filter. Following is the configuration for  metric filter and alarm.

```py
logs.put_metric_filter(
        logGroupName='/aws/lambda/' + functionname,
        filterName=functionname +'_error_stage',
        filterPattern='"ERROR"',
        metricTransformations=[
            {
                'metricName': functionname +'_error_stage',
                'metricNamespace': 'lamda_error',
                'metricValue': '1',
                'defaultValue': 0
            },
        ]
    )
```

Configuration for metric alarm.

```py
cloudwatch.put_metric_alarm(
        ActionsEnabled=True,
        AlarmActions=[
            "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:653453327677:logs_error_mail"
        ],
        AlarmName=alarm_name,
        ComparisonOperator= "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold",
        EvaluationPeriods=1,
        InsufficientDataActions=[],
        MetricName=function_name + '_error_stage',
        Namespace="lamda_error",
        OKActions=[],
        Period=300,
        Statistic="Sum",
        Threshold=1.0,
        TreatMissingData="missing"
    )
```

Working all fine but the problem is whenever alarm gets triggered, it will also trigger for next 3 consecutive period. It is because alarms is not going back to OK state after five minute period. How to change the configuration so that it does not get triggered falsely.